# Cloudformation Reference Security group in DBCluster

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am creating a Database cluster with two DB instance using cloudformation.

For this i am able to create

`DBSecGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup`

Then i need to reference it in property VpcSecurityGroupIds.

`DBCluster:
  Type: "AWS::RDS::DBCluster"
  VpcSecurityGroupIds: ?`

VpcSecurityGroupIds requires List.
Not sure how i can do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try one of these two:

```
DBCluster:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
  Properties:
    VpcSecurityGroupIds:
      - !GetAtt DBSecGroup.GroupId

DBCluster:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
  Properties:
    VpcSecurityGroupIds:
      - !Ref DBSecGroup
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#w2ab1c21c10d102d104c13